# e.nodeName is undefined jQuery (not working on Firefox only)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing a basic form with an AJAX response but it didn't work (only) in FireFox; throwing this error in console:

```
TypeError: e.nodeName is undefined.
```

Here is my form (index.php) :

```
<div id="frmContact">
<div id="mail-status"></div>
<div>
    <label style="padding-top:20px;">Name</label>
    <span id="userName-info" class="info"></span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Email</label>
    <span id="userEmail-info" class="info"></span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Subject</label> 
    <span id="subject-info" class="info"></span><br/>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="demoInputBox">
</div>
<div>
    <label>Content</label> 
    <span id="content-info" class="info"></span><br/>
    <textarea name="content" id="content" class="demoInputBox" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
<button name="submit" class="btnAction" onClick="sendContact();">Send</button>
</div>
```

My javascript (end of index.php file) :

```
    <script>
function sendContact() {
    var valid;  
    valid = validateContact();
    if(valid) {
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "contact_mail.php",
        data:'userName='+$("#userName").val()+'&userEmail='+$("#userEmail").val()+'&subject='+$("#subject").val()+'&content='+$(content).val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        },
        error:function (){}
        });
    }
}

function validateContact() {
    var valid = true;   
    $(".demoInputBox").css('background-color','');
    $(".info").html('');

    if(!$("#userName").val()) {
        $("#userName-info").html("(required)");
        $("#userName").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#userEmail").val()) {
        $("#userEmail-info").html("(required)");
        $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#userEmail").val().match(/^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/)) {
        $("#userEmail-info").html("(invalid)");
        $("#userEmail").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#subject").val()) {
        $("#subject-info").html("(required)");
        $("#subject").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }
    if(!$("#content").val()) {
        $("#content-info").html("(required)");
        $("#content").css('background-color','#FFFFDF');
        valid = false;
    }

    return valid;
}
```

And contact_mail.php is the mail php function.

Thanks for help people.

Comment: Can you try : `data:{'userName':$("#userName").val(),'userEmail':$("#userEmail").val(),'subject':$("#subject").val(),'content':$(content).val()}`

Comment: Thanks for your help but your solution don't work. I give you a link of my work : http://formjquery.livehost.fr/ (with your solution). Maybe you'll see it better !

Comment: could you add [unminified jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js) for debugging

Answer (score 2):

The Data from your code:

```
{'userName':$("#userName").val(),'userEmail':$("#userEmail").val(),'subjec‌t':$("#subject").val(),'content':$(content).val()}
```

Where as it should be

```
{'userName':$("#userName").val(),'userEmail':$("#userEmail").val(),'subjec‌t':$("#subject").val(),'content':$('#content').val()}
```

The content should be $('#content')

Thats all :)